# Automatic plot generation on 2 factors subset

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm am trying to write a automatic plot generator based on `DF` subsets on two factors.

I explain myself step by step. Here is a part of my `DF`:

```
YEAR    RN  DATE    NOM SITE    LONG    SP  SUMNB   NB100   DIFF    IA
2001    RNN066  2001-04-26  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel     Humbert  231 Aphantopus hyperantus (Linnaeus, 1758)  0.000000    0.0000000   NA     NA
2001    RNN066  2001-07-04  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Humbert  231 Aphantopus hyperantus (Linnaeus, 1758)  4.000000    1.7316017   69  59.740260
2001    RNN066  2001-07-17  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Pogo 231 Aphantopus hyperantus (Linnaeus, 1758)  2.000000    0.8658009   13  5.627706
2001    RNN066  2001-08-01  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Pogo 231 Aphantopus hyperantus (Linnaeus, 1758)  2.000000    0.8658009   15  6.493506
2001    RNN066  2001-10-03  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Humbert  231 Aphantopus hyperantus (Linnaeus, 1758)  0.000000    0.0000000   63  0.000000
2001    RNN066  2001-04-26  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Humbert  231 Aporia crataegi (Linnaeus, 1758)    0.000000    0.0000000   NA  NA
2001    RNN066  2001-06-04  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Humbert  231 Aporia crataegi (Linnaeus, 1758)    4.000000    1.7316017   39  33.766234
2001    RNN066  2001-06-21  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Pogo 231 Aporia crataegi (Linnaeus, 1758)    16.000000   6.9264069   17  58.874459
2001    RNN066  2001-06-28  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Humbert  231 Aporia crataegi (Linnaeus, 1758)    16.000000   6.9264069   7   24.242424
2001    RNN066  2001-07-04  RAVIN DE VALBOIS    RNN066-Valbois Pel Pogo 231 Aporia crataegi (Linnaeus, 1758)    2.000000    0.8658009   6   2.597403
```

I would like to draw a plot of YEAR~IA for every SP+SITE combination.
I tried apply function but it didnt considered my ggplot() as a function for obscure reasons and ddply() doesnt fits.

I will get a huge amount of plots (thousands) so i need to set them right. That's why i would like to write the SITE name and SP name on the headline of the plot as well as saving each plot with a name depending on SITE and SP. All my attempts of naming the current values of each factor failed.

I'm considering loops but it may be a time consuming command.

EDIT:

Here is my attempt:

```
tapply(SUBTOT$SITE,SUBTOT$SP,function(x){
  ggplot(SUBTOT, aes(YEAR, IA))+
    geom_point(size=3) +
    geom_line(size=1) +
    ggtitle("IA Evolution")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "bottom")+
    guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
} )
```

It's running for each SP but not each SITE value, resulting in identical plots.

Comment: Show us your attempts, add your code to the question, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your function `function(x){ ... }`, you never actually call `x`, but instead use the original data `SUBTOT`. That is the reason, why you get the same plot many times. I also don't think that `tapply` is the suitable function. I would use `dlply` from the `plyr` package instead. Here's my solution:

```
require(plyr)
p <- dlply(SUBTOT, .(SITE, SP),function(x){
  ggplot(x, aes(YEAR, IA))+
    geom_point(size=3) +
    geom_line(size=1) +
    ggtitle("IA Evolution")+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "bottom")+
    guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
})
# only run the following if you want to actually print all your (thousands) of plots. 
# you may want to save them (ggsave) instead. 
lapply(p, print)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on how to set x in the ggplot formula! It is working great!